# How do I check whether a vector is equal to another vector that contains NaN and inf?

Tags: rust

I have a test of division, where I sometimes need to check that my results are either `NaN` or `inf`, but it seems like Rust does not consider NaN to be equal to NaN:

```
fn main() {
    let nan = "NaN".parse::<f64>().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", nan);
    println!("{:?}", nan == nan);
} // NaN false
```

How do I compare two vectors that contain NaN and infinity to see whether they are equal?

Comment: What do you want the result to be if there are NaN/inf?

Comment: FYI, there's a [`NAN` constant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f64/constant.NAN.html); you don't need to involve parsing.

Comment: Potentially relevant information is available in http://stackoverflow.com/q/39638363/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/26489701/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/28247990/155423.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NaN`s by definition compare unequal.  If you want to do something different you've got to define the comparison by yourself.  It's not too difficult; the iterator methods do most of the work for you:

```
fn eq_with_nan_eq(a: f64, b: f64) -> bool {
    (a.is_nan() && b.is_nan()) || (a == b)
}

fn vec_compare(va: &[f64], vb: &[f64]) -> bool {
    (va.len() == vb.len()) &&  // zip stops at the shortest
     va.iter()
       .zip(vb)
       .all(|(a,b)| eq_with_nan_eq(*a,*b))
}

fn main() {
    use std::f64::NAN;
    let a = vec![0f64, 1.0, NAN];
    let b = vec![0f64, 2.0, NAN];
    let c = vec![0f64, 1.0, NAN, 4.0];
    let d = vec![0f64, 1.0, 3.0];

    assert_eq!(vec_compare(&a, &b), false);
    assert_eq!(vec_compare(&a, &a), true);
    assert_eq!(vec_compare(&a, &d), false);
    assert_eq!(vec_compare(&a, &c), false);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7a0a0e0b102a9bf0b494d21b9729babb&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 7):

You might be interested in the [`is_nan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.is_nan) method.

```
assert!(nan.is_nan());
```