# Is there an equivalent to C++ comparator objects for BTreeMap and other things that rely on Ord?

Tags: c++, data-structures, floating-point, rust

I can't seem to accomplish the same things with the `Ord` trait that I was able to with C++ comparator objects. Take this simplification of more complicated scenarios for example:

```cpp
int epsilon = 0.001;
auto less = [epsilon](const double a, const double b) {
                if (fabs(a - b) > epsilon) {
                    return a < b;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
std::map<float, int, decltype(less)> myMap(less);
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(1.0, 1));
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(2.0, 2));
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(3.0, 3));

auto found = myMap.find(1.0001);
assert(found != myMap.end());
assert(found->second == 1);
```

I want a comparator to have some runtime context, like an epsilon value. I can't figure out how you would do this with `BTreeMap` since I can't add state to the `Ord` trait. Is there some technique I haven't figured out yet to do the equivalent?

**EDIT**

I had a typo in my example that prevented me from realizing the C++ didn't actually work. I'm reevaluating the problem.

Comment: `int epsilon = 0.001;` => if you provide snipped please read [mcve].

Comment: (side remark) Note that your `less` does not define a valid order for use in `std::map`, according to the C++ standard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a HashMap with f64 as key in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638363/how-can-i-use-a-hashmap-with-f64-as-key-in-rust)

Comment: Your question is not about finding an element in a hashmap/btree (that's easy, just use [`find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) on the iterator), but instead how to use a float/double as a key in a hashmap.

Comment: @hellow except that `find` on the iterator uses linear time, whereas a binary tree allows for logarithmic time.

Comment: That's right Jmb, I think that should be improved. I opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54550), thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, your C++ code is flawed: `less` is not transitive. For example, [if you follow this link](http://cpp.sh/2mq5e) you'll see I sort a vector `{ 2.0, 1.0, 0.0 }` with an epsilon of 1.0; the resulting "sorted" vector is `{ 0.0, 2.0, 1.0 }` even though according to `less` both `0.0` and `1.0` are equal and therefore should be adjacent. In general, epsilon-based comparisons are not transitive, and therefore cannot be used to define an order that `sort` or `map` can use.

Comment: This may be far too late to be of any use to you @jsadusk, but for future readers of this question it may be helpful to know that my (recently published) [copse](https://crates.io/crates/copse) crate provides an alternative BTreeSet that can be instantiated with a custom/runtime-defined comparator.

Answer (score 6):

There is a reason why floating point types do not implement `Ord`. The internals of `BTreeMap` make assumptions about implementors of `Ord`, which allow it to be more efficient, but if those assumptions turn out to be incorrect, then it can lead to Undefined Behaviour, because these assumptions are relied upon in `unsafe` code. Floating points cannot satisfy these assumptions because of the existence of `NaN`, values that represent infinity and the nature of floating point arithmetic which means the "same" number can have different binary representations.

Your C++ code is likely to suffer from the same issues, but sometimes code with Undefined Behaviour just seems to work. Until one day when it doesn't - that's just the nature of Undefined Behaviour!

Floating points are good for representing measures or where the values can have massively varying orders of magnitude. If you do a calculation about the distances between cities and the numbers are off by a few nanometres, you don't care. You'll never have to find another city that is *exactly* the same distance as London is from New York. More likely you'll be happy to search for a city that is the same distance to the nearest 1 km - a number that you can compare as an integer.

Which brings me to the question of *why* are you using floating point numbers as keys? What does it mean to you and what are you trying to store there? Is `f64::NAN` a value that you want to be valid? Is `45.00000000001` the "same" as `45.00000000001001`? Are you just as likely to be storing very large numbers as very tiny numbers? Is exact equality something that makes sense for these numbers? Are they the result of a computation, which could have rounding errors?

It's not possible to tell you what to do here, but I can suggest that you look at your real problem and model it in a way that reflects your real constraints. If you only care about a specific precision, then round the numbers to that precision and store them in a [fixed-point type](https://crates.io/crates/fixed), or an integer, or perhaps a [rational](https://crates.io/crates/num-rational), all of which implement `Ord`.

Based on your C++ code, it looks like you are happy with a precision of `0.001`. So you can store your keys as integers - you'll just have to remember to do the conversion and multiply/divide by 1000 as appropriate. You'll have to deal with the possibility of `NaN` and infinities, but you'll do it in safe code, so you won't have to worry about UB.

Here is how you could use the `num-rational` crate to get something with similar behaviour to your C++ code:

```
extern crate num_rational; // 0.2.1

use num_rational::Rational64;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn in_thousandths(n: f64) -> Rational64 {
    // you may want to include further validation here to deal with `NaN` or infinities
    let denom = 1000;
    Rational64::new_raw((n * denom as f64) as i64, denom)
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();

    map.insert(in_thousandths(1.0), 1);
    map.insert(in_thousandths(2.0), 2);
    map.insert(in_thousandths(3.0), 3);

    let value = map.get(&1.into());
    assert_eq!(Some(&1), value);
}
```

Comment: `in_thousandths(std::f64::NAN)` -> `Ratio { numer: -9223372036854775808, denom: 1000 }`. Still not a good one :( Float sucks!

Comment: @hellow It's not UB though.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use your own type and implement yourself Ord trait:

```
#[derive(PartialOrd, Debug)]
struct MyNumber {
    value: f64,
}

impl MyNumber {
    const EPSILON: f64 = 0.001;
    fn new(value: f64) -> Self {
        Self { value }
    }
}

impl PartialEq for MyNumber {
    fn eq(&self, other: &MyNumber) -> bool {
        if f64::abs(self.value - other.value) < MyNumber::EPSILON {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

impl Eq for MyNumber {}

use std::cmp::Ordering;

impl Ord for MyNumber {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &MyNumber) -> Ordering {
        if self == other {
            Ordering::Equal
        } else if self < other {
            Ordering::Less
        } else {
            Ordering::Greater
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use std::collections::BTreeMap;

    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert(MyNumber::new(1.0), 1);
    map.insert(MyNumber::new(2.0), 2);
    map.insert(MyNumber::new(3.0), 3);

    println!("{:?}", map.get(&MyNumber::new(1.0001)));
}
```

But I think it doesn't match the requirement for a BTreeMap.

Comment: There is a reason that f64 does not implement `Ord` and you should not blindly implement it. This will lead to various errors! (Think what will happen in case of `Inf` or `Nan`)

Comment: @hellow Yes, but that not me who want to do that.

Comment: But you are pointing into that direction. You should not suggest a "wrong" solution. For a specific reason why one should not do this, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638363/how-can-i-use-a-hashmap-with-f64-as-key-in-rust

Comment: Your newtype could enforce that infinities and NaN are not allowed, a bit like NonZeroUsize and friends. That would remove the UB.

Comment: @PeterHall This is not enough NaN and other is not the only problem, Ord require "transitive, a < b and b < c implies a < c. The same must hold for both == and >." with this code we can have a == b equal to true, b == c also equal to true but a == c could be false. But [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8b803eb567b4c0689ff2f773d6161013&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) my attempt to make the code unreadable ;) so whatever this is impossible to make for a BTreeMap. The type is simple not designed for this kind a data.

Comment: @Stargateur Oh yeah, I forgot about the symmetry with ==

Comment: @Stargateur The documentation on both [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) and [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) require that implementing types satisfy transitivity. Are you implying that floating point types are erroneously implementing these traits?

Comment: @E_net4 No, but standard just compare with strict equality but it's quite pointless for floating number. I just said that if you use an epsilon value you can't have transitivity.

Answer (score -2):

The way to do that in rust is to wrap your key in a [newtype](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/master/patterns/newtype.md) and implement `Ord` the way you want it:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

const EPSILON: f64 = 0.001;

struct MyFloat (f64);

impl Ord for MyFloat {
    fn cmp (&self, other: &MyFloat) -> Ordering {
        if (self.0 - other.0).abs() < EPSILON {
            // I assume that this is what you wanted even though the C++ example
            // does the opposite
            Ordering::Equal
        } else if self.0 < other.0 {
            Ordering::Less
        } else {
            Ordering::Greater
        }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for MyFloat {
    fn partial_cmp (&self, other: &MyFloat) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some (self.cmp (other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for MyFloat {
    fn eq (&self, other: &MyFloat) -> bool {
        (self.0 - other.0).abs() < EPSILON
    }
}

impl Eq for MyFloat {}

fn main() {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert (MyFloat (1.0), 1);
    map.insert (MyFloat (2.0), 2);
    map.insert (MyFloat (3.0), 3);

    let found = map.get (&MyFloat (1.00001));
    println!("Found: {:?}", found);
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=680e4ca8a0ba23770f7c4a270d9dec3e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Note that this will only work if the keys are finite and spaced by more than `EPSILON`.

Comment: There is a reason that f64 does not implement `Ord` and you should not blindly implement it. This will lead to various errors! (Think what will happen in case of `Inf` or `Nan`)

Comment: That issue is also present in the OP's C++ code. I've edited the answer to make the limitations more apparent.

Comment: @Jmb: If there are issues in the OP code, then the appropriate answer is to correct the OP's assumptions (a frame challenge) rather than blindly reproduce the errors in the answer.