# Can I specialise a trait on a nested type?

Tags: rust

I have a queue `Strategy` trait with implementations for `Monotonic` and `LastTick` parameterised on the type I want to insert:

```
struct Monotonic<T> {
    items: Vec<T>,
}
struct LastTick<T> {
    items: Vec<T>,
}

struct SetDelta;

trait Strategy<T> {
    type T;
    fn enqueue(&mut self, v: T);
    fn has_pending(&self) -> bool;
}

impl<T> Strategy<T> for Monotonic<T> {
    type T = Self;
    fn enqueue(&mut self, v: T) {
        self.items.push(v);
    }
    fn has_pending(&self) -> bool {
        !self.items.is_empty()
    }
}

impl<T> Strategy<T> for LastTick<T> {
    type T = Self;
    fn enqueue(&mut self, v: T) {
        self.items.push(v);
    }
    fn has_pending(&self) -> bool {
        !self.items.is_empty()
    }
}

impl<T> Strategy<T> for LastTick<T> {
    type T = Self;
    fn enqueue(&mut self, v: T) {
        self.items.push(v);
    }
    fn has_pending(&self) -> bool {
        !self.items.is_empty()
    }
}

impl<T> LastTick<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        LastTick { items: Vec::new() }
    }
}
impl<T> Monotonic<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Monotonic { items: Vec::new() }
    }
}

#[test]
fn monotonic_scalar_queue() {
    let mut a = Monotonic::<f64>::new();
    a.enqueue(123.4);
    assert!(a.has_pending());
}

#[test]
fn monotonic_list_queue() {
    let mut a = Monotonic::<[f64; 3]>::new();
    a.enqueue([123.4, 345.8, 324.1]);
    assert!(a.has_pending());
}

#[test]
fn monotonic_tuple_queue() {
    let mut a = Monotonic::<(f64, String, u32)>::new();
    a.enqueue((123.4, "hello".into(), 324));
    assert!(a.has_pending());
}
```

The above work fine. I want to keep the same interface for a `HashSet` where the behaviour is slightly different.

```
#[test]
fn monotonic_set_queue() {
    let mut a = Monotonic::<HashSet<f64>>::new();
    // I want to insert a f64 and implement the logic of the hashset in
    // the implementation, but it expects a new HashSet
    a.enqueue(123.4);
    assert!(a.has_pending());
}
```

I tried

```
impl<T> Strategy<T> for Monotonic<HashSet<f64>> {
    type T = Self;
    fn enqueue(&mut self, v: T) {
        self.items.push(v);
    }
    fn has_pending(&self) -> bool {
        !self.items.is_empty()
    }
}
```

and also

```
impl Strategy<f64> for Monotonic<f64> {
    type T = HashSet<f64>;
    fn enqueue(&mut self, v: f64) {
        self.items.push(v);
    }
    fn has_pending(&self) -> bool {
        !self.items.is_empty()
    }
}
```

with different results, but no luck. Is there a way to specify this easily?

Comment: See also [How can I use a HashMap with f64 as key in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39638363/155423); [How to do a binary search on a Vec of floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28247990/155423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want a different implementation of `Monotonic<T>`, where the collection is not a `Vec` - that's not possible with the way you have currently defined `Monotonic`. You could, instead, create another type `MonotonicHashSet<T>`, and use `HashSet` as the backing collection.

If, instead, you would like to make `Monotonic` accept different collection types, then you may want to also genericize it over the collection type. This, however, could get complicated quickly. In Rust, the properties we generally associate with collections are split across several traits, defined in the [`iter` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html). They're split up so that each collection type can define it's behavior granularly and correctly for whatever constraints the collection has. So, for your `Monotonic` and `LastTick` types, it's important to consider what requirements you might have, and what traits that means you will require for collections to be used with that type.

One last note: While `Vec` accepts any type `T`, a `HashSet` requires total equality from the `Eq` trait, and hashability, through the `Hash` trait. These different requirements are worth considering, because unlike, for example, C#, Rust does not provide default implementations of these operations for all types - you have to provide them or [`#[derive()]` them](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-03-derivable-traits.html).

Comment: One last thing - the floating-point types (`f32`& `f64`) don't implement `Eq` or `Hash` - `Eq`, because `NaN` is not equal to any number or itself; and `Hash` because there is no consensus on how to deal with +/-0, NaN, denormals, and there are issues with different bitwise representations (which may hash differently) representing the same number.