# Bug or Non-feature in nightly rust? (trait Specialization)

Tags: rust

So I am currently using

> rustc 1.36.0-nightly (8dd4aae9a 2019-05-04)

and in my lib.rs I enabled

> #![feature(specialization)]

And in a module of my library crate, I have the following, which does not compile. From my understanding it should compile, even without `specialization` but it does not - in either case.

```
use std::hash::{Hash,Hasher};


#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone,PartialEq,Eq)]
struct HashKey<T>(T);

//default 
impl<T : Hash> Hash for HashKey<T> {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) 
        where H : Hasher
    {
        self.0.hash(state)
    }
}

impl Hash for HashKey<f32> {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) 
        where H : Hasher
    {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<f32,u32>(self.0) }.hash(state)
    }
}

impl Hash for HashKey<f64> {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) 
        where H : Hasher
    {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<f64,u64>(self.0) }.hash(state)
    }
}
```

As we all know, `f32` as well as `f64` are neither `Eq` nor `Hash` because of the `NaN` problem as discussed for example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638363/how-can-i-use-a-hashmap-with-f64-as-key-in-rust). Using the unsafe `reinterpret_cast<u32>` workaround as I do not care about `Nan` in my case.

So, I have an impl of trait Hash for any `HashKey<T> where T : Hash` and I have impls for both `f32` and `f64` which are as pointed out not `Hash`. As such, it is not even a specialization as those 3 impls cover *orthogonal* cases.

Despite all that wonderful logic, I get the error:

```
conflicting implementations of trait `std::hash::Hash` for type `naive::HashKey<f32>`:

conflicting implementation for `naive::HashKey<f32>`

note: upstream crates may add new impl of trait `std::hash::Hash` for type `f32` in future versionsrustc(E0119)
naive.rs(10, 1): first implementation here
naive.rs(18, 1): conflicting implementation for `naive::HashKey<f32>`
```

Which leads to the questions:

Am I doing something wrong? How to do it right? Why is this a problem in the first place, given those impls refer to sets of types with no overlap?

Comment: Without the specialization feature, this is not expected to compile, for exactly the reason given in the error message. The specialization feature is only incompletely specified and implemented, and currently has bugs and soundness holes; I don't know the exact state of affairs there. I suggest using one of the wrapper that implement `Hash` for floating-point numbers, like the `ordered_float` crate.

Comment: @SvenMarnach But WHY are they conflicting? ``HashKey<f32>`` is a different type than ``HashKey<f64>`` which is different from all types in the set ``HashKey<T> where T: Hash``. I simply cannot find a state of mind where I can see a conflict.

Comment: @BitTickler The specialization feature is nowhere near ready to use. I didn't read your question carefully, but my experience of the feature is that it mostly hasn't worked how I hoped.

Comment: @BitTickler I think this is the classic "trait you don't own on a type you don't own", the compiler isn't ok with relying on the fact that `f32: !Hash` because that could change.

Comment: @BitTickler It's actually in the error message: "upstream crates may add new impl of trait `std::hash::Hash` for type `f32` in future versions" I did not repeat that, because it was already included in your question.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sorry, I am not psychic and have no crystal ball either. As such I dismissed that "in the future" part as gibberish. I can only program against the status quo not against a future I cannot foresee. On a more serious note, do they have that hard coded in the compiler? ``if t == "f32" { special_behavior() }``?

Comment: @BitTickler No, it applies to any type. The situation that implementing a previously unimplemented trait breaks downstream crates is disallowed in general, to ensure that implementing additional traits is always a backwards-compatible change. This is what the note in the error message tries to explain – sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: To put it yet another way, the compiler tells you that there is a _potential_ conflict due to possible future extensions of an upstream crate, so it conservatively rejects your code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Now I think I understand. I can impl upstream traits for types in my crate, but not upstream traits for upstream  types That makes sense, kind of. Thanks for that explanation.