# How to remove duplicates from a vector of structures?

Tags: rust

I have a struct and a vector of them:

```rust
enum MySize {
    Big,
    Small,
    Medium,
    Huge,
}

struct MyStruct {
    my_size: MySize,
    field1: String,
    field2: u64,
    field3: f64,
}

let mut my_structs: Vec<MyStruct> = get_data_with_duplicates();
//how to remove duplicates from 'my_structs'?
```

I'm aware of `sort_by` and `dedup_by`, but I only know how to use them with the primitive types. In my case these methods can't be applied as are, right?

How to remove duplicates then?

Comment: Your struct has to implement the `PartialEq` Trait, and it will work

Comment: Why cannot you use those functions?

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=21d28580f231a710ed185d6e526bebd9)

Comment: Since you have a floating point number, you might be interested in [Using max_by_key on a vector of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37127209/155423); [How to do a binary search on a Vec of floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28247990/155423); [How can I use a HashMap with f64 as key in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39638363/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster that doesn't work

Comment: @tajara show me how it doesn't work

Comment: @Shepmaster `^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `MyStruct == MyStruct``. That is, `PartialOrd` isn't implemented

Comment: @tajara that doesn't explain anything, unfortunately. The [code I provided you](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=21d28580f231a710ed185d6e526bebd9) calls `dedup` on a vector of your structs, as you've asked. It compiles successfully. `==` uses [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html), not `PartialOrd`, so I don't follow your point. Perhaps you can use [the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to **show me** how you have modified the working code to make it non-working?

Comment: @Shepmaster from my project: https://i.postimg.cc/3NL1drsq/Captura-de-pantalla-2019-09-11-a-la-s-19-46-43.png

Comment: @Shepmaster https://i.postimg.cc/DwbVkRsh/Captura-de-pantalla-2019-09-11-a-la-s-19-51-41.png

Comment: that is, why do you call "dedup" without calling "sort" first?

Comment: @Shepmaster your cooooode won't wooooork

Answer (score 2):

the `dedup` family of functions will not help you without a ton of extra work, as they only clear *neighboring* duplicates. the `sort` family of functions requires `Ord` to function, which requires `Eq` as well. As such, you have three options open to you:

- You can implement [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) (it can be used in `#[derive]`) and [`Hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html) (which can also be `#[derive]`d if all fields implement `Hash`) on your `struct` and then convert your `Vec` into a [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E). This allows you to get a very performant set primitive out of the box
- You can implement a [naive filter (playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b369fc73f2978098d7f178624273490a) with a memory and processing complexity of `O(N)`, which keeps an internal state of all the visited nodes and simply filters based on it. The only requirement for this method is `PartialEq`, which is easy to `#[derive]`. This can be optimized further. The current code is below, implemented as an extension trait to allow you to reuse it wherever you like:

  ```
    trait Dedup<T: PartialEq + Clone> {
        fn clear_duplicates(&mut self);
    }

    impl<T: PartialEq + Clone> Dedup<T> for Vec<T> {
        fn clear_duplicates(&mut self) {
            let mut already_seen = Vec::new();
            self.retain(|item| match already_seen.contains(item) {
                true => false,
                _ => {
                    already_seen.push(item.clone());
                    true
                }
            })
        }
    }
  ```

There are other implementations/ways of doing it, but those are some of the quickest.

Comment: Nice `clear_duplicates` function! As an optimization, the `already_seen` vector could be constructed with `Vec::with_capacity(self.len())` to avoid resizing the vector while while processing. For vectors with a lot of duplicates this would increase memory overhead, but if there are few duplicates it should decrease CPU instructions from vector resizing.